# Can I execute selenium test cases in a real browser with Jenkins Selenium and Maven

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, jenkins, browsers

I am working on selenium project with Jenkins + Maven + Selenium + TestNG

I have following questions.

1. Can I execute selenium test cases in Jenkins by launching browsers?
   Currently it gets executed without browser.

If yes, how can I achieve this?

2. Ideally what Maven goal is set for build execution.
3. By default test report is saved in `projectfolder/target/surefire-reports/`. How can I change this location?

Comment: Retitled (from "doubts about Maven...") to first point to be a better question for the community.  I would make the 2nd and 3rd points different question as we'd like questions to be general enough to be more applicable to others

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can I execute selenium testcases in Jenkins by launch browsers (Currently it gets executed without browser :( . ), If yes then how can I achive this.

Depends on the operating system.  For Linux, the Jenkins executor must have an X connection in order to start a browser.  Either that, or you must use Selenium Grid to launch a browser on some other machine.  See for example [this article](https://anadea.info/blog/selenium-grid-with-jenkins-good-tandem-for-parallel-tests) on Selenium Grid.

> 2. Ideally what maven goal is set for build execution.

test